# mysql replace function not expected results

Tags: mysql, replace

select replace(lastname,'%%',firstname) as new1 from names;

When I run this, lastname is returned. Why? I expect it to search names.lastname for everything (%% wildcard) and return names.firstname.

All the syntax I have reviewed suggest I am doing this right, it seems so simple...

Comment: this query does not make sense. Why not simply return `select firstname`?

Comment: `replace()` does not take wildcards.  You are confusing it with `like`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Why?**

The expression `REPLACE(lastname,'%%',firstname)` will return `lastname`, whenever `lastname` doesn't contain two contiguous percent sign characters. Why? Because that's the documented behavior of the `REPLACE` function.

The **'%'** is a wildcard when used with `LIKE`. It's *not* a wildcard in the `REPLACE()` function.

The expression in your question will search the value of **`lastname`** for occurrences of two contiguous percent sign characters, and replace those occurrences with the value in **`firstname`**.

For example:

```
SELECT REPLACE('fee%%fi%%fo','%%','-dah ') AS foo

foo                
-------------------
fee-dah fi-dah fo
```

(I believe this answers the question you asked.)

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve?

I'm pretty sure wildcards are not allowed in `REPLACE`, but the way you have written it suggests that you want to `SELECT` the `lastname` with all its characters replaced with the string `firstname`, which is the same as `SELECT firstname`.

If you need to change the `lastname` in the table, you will need to run an `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE names SET lastname=firstname
```

If you simply want a concatenation of the two then `SELECT CONCAT(lastname,' ', firstname)` is your game.